# Do we have Sql Query That Returns Single Digits Like "One Two Three" When we give input 123?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Input : 123
Output : One Two Three

No Hundreds No Thousand No Thirty-Twenty Only Clean Digits are to be spelled.Has Anyone Got an Idea about it ?

Comment: It'll depend on what SQL engine you're using (but the answer is probably 'no')

Comment: What database? MS SQL Server, MS Access, PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc.?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In *SQL-Server* you can do It with `CASE` statement, you have to use `COALESCE` to convert null values to blank strings, something like:

```
DECLARE @val INT = 123

SELECT COALESCE(CASE WHEN @val LIKE '%0%' THEN 'Zero '  END,'') +
       COALESCE(CASE WHEN @val LIKE '%1%' THEN 'One '   END,'') +
       COALESCE(CASE WHEN @val LIKE '%2%' THEN 'Two '   END,'') +
       COALESCE(CASE WHEN @val LIKE '%3%' THEN 'Three ' END,'') +
       COALESCE(CASE WHEN @val LIKE '%4%' THEN 'Four '  END,'') +
       COALESCE(CASE WHEN @val LIKE '%5%' THEN 'Five '  END,'') +
       COALESCE(CASE WHEN @val LIKE '%6%' THEN 'Six '   END,'') +
       COALESCE(CASE WHEN @val LIKE '%7%' THEN 'Seven ' END,'') +
       COALESCE(CASE WHEN @val LIKE '%8%' THEN 'Eight ' END,'') +
       COALESCE(CASE WHEN @val LIKE '%9%' THEN 'Nine '  END,'')
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
One Two Three
```

---

As per *Gordon Linoff* comment you can avoid `COALESCE` by adding `ELSE` clause:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @val LIKE '%0%' THEN 'Zero '  ELSE '' END +
       CASE WHEN @val LIKE '%1%' THEN 'One '   ELSE '' END +
       CASE WHEN @val LIKE '%2%' THEN 'Two '   ELSE '' END +
       CASE WHEN @val LIKE '%3%' THEN 'Three ' ELSE '' END +
       CASE WHEN @val LIKE '%4%' THEN 'Four '  ELSE '' END +
       CASE WHEN @val LIKE '%5%' THEN 'Five '  ELSE '' END +
       CASE WHEN @val LIKE '%6%' THEN 'Six '   ELSE '' END +
       CASE WHEN @val LIKE '%7%' THEN 'Seven ' ELSE '' END +
       CASE WHEN @val LIKE '%8%' THEN 'Eight ' ELSE '' END +
       CASE WHEN @val LIKE '%9%' THEN 'Nine '  ELSE '' END
```

**UPDATE**

As per comment that this will not work with number like '3421', updated code to work in situation like this:

```
DECLARE @val NVARCHAR(40) = '412'
DECLARE @i INT = 1
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(       
    Val NVARCHAR(40),
    IdRn INT
)
WHILE (@i < LEN(@val) + 1)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES
       (CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@val,@i,1) LIKE '0' THEN 'Zero '  ELSE '' END, @i),
       (CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@val,@i,1) LIKE '1' THEN 'One '   ELSE '' END, @i),
       (CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@val,@i,1) LIKE '2' THEN 'Two '   ELSE '' END, @i),
       (CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@val,@i,1) LIKE '3' THEN 'Three ' ELSE '' END, @i),
       (CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@val,@i,1) LIKE '4' THEN 'Four '  ELSE '' END, @i),
       (CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@val,@i,1) LIKE '5' THEN 'Five '  ELSE '' END, @i),
       (CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@val,@i,1) LIKE '6' THEN 'Six '   ELSE '' END, @i),
       (CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@val,@i,1) LIKE '7' THEN 'Seven ' ELSE '' END, @i),
       (CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@val,@i,1) LIKE '8' THEN 'Eight ' ELSE '' END, @i),
       (CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@val,@i,1) LIKE '9' THEN 'Nine '  ELSE '' END, @i) 
SET @i = @i + 1
END

DECLARE @Nums VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT @Nums = COALESCE(@Nums + ' ', '') + Val 
FROM #Temp
WHERE Val <> '' 

SELECT @Nums
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Four  One  Two
```

Comment: A requirement is to convert 123 into one, two, three... Do you want to list all digits?

Comment: Yup i tried with case but for 2 or 4 digit numbers i require to split them up

Comment: Misunderstood question before, @Nikul check updated answer

Comment: Why would you use `coalesce()` when you can just add an `else` clause?

Comment: This will only work if the number is not repeated and is ascending order.  The number 3421 will read as 'One Two Three Four '.

Comment: @nealkernohan updated my answer with working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
declare @Input varchar(max)='123'
declare @ouput varchar(max)='' 
declare @temp int=1 
declare @char nvarchar(max)=''

WHILE @temp <=LEN(@Input) 
BEGIN
set @char = SUBSTRING(@Input, @temp, 1)
set @ouput += (case when @char=1 then 'One ' 
when @char=2 then 'Two '    
when @char=3 then 'Three ' 
else 'so on ' end)
SET @temp = @temp + 1;
END;
print @ouput
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.   I cannot think of a shorter way offhand.

This handles numbers that occur more than once in the Input string.

```
DECLARE @Input varchar(max)

SET @Input = '12307823'

DECLARE @Result TABLE(Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), Value VARCHAR(1))
DECLARE @Mapping TABLE (Id int identity(0,1), Word varchar(6))
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(1)
DECLARE @ind Int

INSERT @Mapping (Word) VALUES 
                        ( 'Zero '), ('One '),( 'Two ' ), ( 'Three '),
                        ( 'Four ' ), ( 'Five ' ), ( 'Six ' ), ( 'Seven ' ),
                        ( 'Eight '), ( 'Nine '), ( 'Ten ')

IF(@Input is not null)
BEGIN
    SET @ind = 1
    WHILE LEN(@Input) > 1
    BEGIN
            SET @str = SUBSTRING(@Input,@ind,1)
            SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input,@ind+1,LEN(@Input)-@ind)
            INSERT INTO @Result values (@str)
    END
    SET @str = @Input
    INSERT INTO @Result values (@str)
END 

SELECT STUFF((SELECT Word
    FROM @Result r INNER JOIN @Mapping m
    ON r.Value = m.Id ORDER BY r.Id
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 0, '') AS ConcatenatedString
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use something similar to dictionary:

```
--input
DECLARE @input INT = 456
-- create "dictionary" table
DECLARE @dictionary TABLE(cKey INT, cValue VARCHAR(30))
-- create destination table
DECLARE @dest TABLE(cInput INT, cID INT, cDigit INT, cValue VARCHAR(30))

--insert data into dictionary 
INSERT INTO @dictionary (cKey, cValue)
VALUES(0, 'zero'), (1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three'),
(4, 'four'), (5, 'five'), (6, 'six'), (7, 'seven'), (8, 'eight'), (9, 'nine')

-- use CTE to split digits
--- and insert data into destination table
;WITH CTE AS
(
    --initial value
    SELECT 1 AS ID, @input AS InputValue, @input AS Digit, NULL AS Remainder
    WHERE LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), @input))=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS ID, @input AS InputValue, CONVERT(INT, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @input), 1)) AS Digit, RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @input), LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @input))-1) AS Remainder
    WHERE LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), @input))>1
    --recursive part
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID+1 AS ID, InputValue, CONVERT(INT, LEFT(Remainder, 1)) AS Digit, RIGHT(Remainder, LEN(Remainder) -1) AS Remainder
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE LEN(Remainder)>1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID+1 AS ID, InputValue, CONVERT(INT, Remainder) AS Digit, NULL AS Remainder
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE LEN(Remainder)=1
)
INSERT INTO @dest (cID, cInput, cDigit, cValue)
SELECT t1.ID, t1.InputValue, t1.Digit, t2.cValue 
FROM CTE t1 LEFT JOIN @dictionary t2 ON t1.Digit = t2.cKey 
ORDER BY t1.ID

--display data
SELECT DISTINCT t1.cInput, STUFF(( SELECT ' ' + t2.cValue  
                FROM @dest t2
                WHERE t2.cInput = t1.cInput 
                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS DigitsAsWords
FROM @dest t1
```

**Result:**

```
cInput  DigitsAsWords
456     four five six
```

For further information, please see: [WITH Common Table Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

*Note:* the best solution for such of requirements is not to use pure SQL, but client side code.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @string as varchar(MAX) = 12845963254
DECLARE @position int,  @Kl As varchar(MAX) ='';

SET @position = 1
WHILE @position <= DATALENGTH(@string)
   BEGIN
   Set @Kl +=(Case CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTRING(@string, @position, 1)))
               when 1 then ' One ' 
               when 2 then ' Two ' 
               when 3 then ' Three ' 
               when 4 then ' Four ' 
               when 5 then ' Five ' 
               when 6 then ' Six ' 
               when 7 then ' Seven ' 
               when 8 then ' Eight ' 
               when 9 then ' Nine ' 
               when 0 then ' Zero ' 
            end)
   SET @position = @position + 1
   END; 
   Select @Kl
GO
```